# nested gridview expand collapse not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

hi i am using this code for nested grid view and there is no error the nested grid view. when on the click of one row plus image the other rows can not be hide automatically. can any one help...

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function divexpandcollapsenew(divname) {

        var div = document.getElementById(divname);
        var img = document.getElementById('imgdiv' + divname);
        if (div.style.display == "none") {
            div.style.display = "inline";
            img.src = "images/minus.gif";
        } else {
            div.style.display = "none";
            img.src = "images/plus.gif";
        }
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#imgBtnClose").click(function (e) {
            HideDialog();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });


    function HideDialog() {
        $("#overlay").hide();
        $("#dialog").fadeOut(100);
    }

</script>
```

Markup

```
<div style="background-image: url(images/bgMW.png);">
    <hr />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <fieldset style="border: none" title="Time Data">
                <div align="center">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblHead" runat="server" class="Heading1" Text="Time Data"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div align="center">
            </fieldset>
            <div id="all" class="divassigngrid">
                <div align="left">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblInfo" Text="Time Data Details" runat="server" CssClass="Heading2"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div align="left" style="width: 778px; margin-left: 0px">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text="From"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" Width="66px" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" onkeypress="return false"
                        OnTextChanged="txtFromDate_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text="To"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" Width="66px" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" AutoPostBack="true" onkeypress="return false"
                        OnTextChanged="txtToDate_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text="Weekly Off"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text="Toooooo" ForeColor="Bisque" BackColor="Bisque"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text="Mismatch"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text="Toooooo" BackColor="LightPink" ForeColor="LightPink"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblerr" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="" Font-Size="Medium" Style="margin-left: 10px"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div align="left">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvAttendance" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" CssClass="grid"
                        EmptyDataText="No Records Found." CellPadding="4" GridLines="Both" SelectedRowStyle-BackColor="#FFFFCC"
                        SelectedRowStyle-CssClass="GV1" OnRowCreated="gvAttendance_RowCreated" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvAttendance_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        OnRowCommand="gvAttendance_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gvAttendance_RowDataBound" OnRowUpdating="gvAttendance_RowUpdating">
                        <FooterStyle CssClass="GV2" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="GV1" />
                        <%--<RowStyle CssClass="GV2" />--%>
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderImageUrl="images/Icon_HeaderLock.jpg">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%-- <asp:Label ID="lblLock" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text="Lock"></asp:Label>--%>
                                    <asp:Image ID="iLock" ImageUrl="images/Icon_HeaderLock.jpg" ToolTip="Lock" Width="12px" Height="12px"
                                        runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderImageUrl="images/Icon_fullday.Jpg">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%--<asp:Label ID="lblLeave" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text="Leave"></asp:Label>--%>
                                    <asp:Image ID="iLeave" ImageUrl="images/Icon_fullday.Jpg" ToolTip="FullDay" Width="12px" Height="12px"
                                        runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderImageUrl="images/Icon_Error.Jpg">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%--<asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text="Error"></asp:Label>--%>
                                    <asp:Image ID="iError" ImageUrl="images/Icon_Error.jpg" Width="12px" Height="12px" runat="server" ToolTip="Error" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20px">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <a href="JavaScript:divexpandcollapsenew('div<%# Eval("Date") %>');">
                                        <img alt="childimg" id="imgdiv<%# Eval("Date")%>"  width="12px" height="12px" border="0" src="images/plus.gif" / >
                                    </a>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblActDate" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text='<%# Eval("Date")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Shift">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblShiftCode" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text='<% # Eval("Shift") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Day">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDay" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text='<% # Eval("Day") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblShiftStatus" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text='<%# Eval("Status")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First In">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblFirstIn" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text='<% # Eval("First In") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Out">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblLastOut" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text='<%# Eval("Last Out")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Eff. Hrs (H)">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEffHrs" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text='<% # Eval("Eff") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Late (M)">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblLate" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text='<%# Eval("Late")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Early (M)">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEarly" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text='<% # Eval("Early") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Permission (M)">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblPermission" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text='<% # Eval("Permission") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="IBAction" runat="server" Width="12px" Height="12px" ImageUrl="~/images/AddInsideGV.png"
                                        CausesValidation="false" ToolTip="Add" CommandName="additem" CommandArgument="Date" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="100%">
                                            <div id="div<%# Eval("Date") %>" style="display: none; position: relative; left: 15px; overflow: auto">
                                                <asp:GridView ID="gvChildGrid" Width="97%" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="grid"
                                                    EmptyDataText="No Records Found." CellPadding="4" GridLines="Both" OnRowCommand="gvChildGrid_RowCommand"
                                                    OnRowEditing="gvChildGrid_OnRowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvChildGrid_RowUpdating" SelectedRowStyle-BackColor="#FFFFCC"
                                                    SelectedRowStyle-CssClass="GV1">
                                                    <FooterStyle CssClass="GV2" />
                                                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GV1" />
                                                    <RowStyle CssClass="GV2" />
                                                    <Columns>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblSwipeDate" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text='<%# Eval("Date")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Swipe Time">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblSwipteTime" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text='<% # Eval("Swipe Time") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mode">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblMode" runat="server" CssClass="lblErr" Text='<%# Eval("Mode")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Change To">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlChangeTo" runat="server" CssClass="ddl">
                                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="IN">IN</asp:ListItem>
                                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="OUT">OUT</asp:ListItem>
                                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="DELETE">DELETE</asp:ListItem>
                                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" CssClass="lbl"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remarks">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRemarks" runat="server" CssClass="ddl">
                                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">---Select---</asp:ListItem>
                                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Wrong Time Data Mode Selected ( In / Out )</asp:ListItem>
                                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Multiple Time Data Entry</asp:ListItem>
                                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Multiple Time Data Entry - System Error</asp:ListItem>
                                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="IBActionInsideGV" runat="server" Width="12px" Height="12px" ImageUrl="~/images/Ratify.gif"
                                                                    CausesValidation="false" ToolTip="Ratify" OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to Ratify?')"
                                                                    CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>' CommandName="RatifyForm" />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    </Columns>
                                                </asp:GridView>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
```

and here is my back end

```
protected void gvAttendance_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gvAttendance.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[i].ToolTip = gvAttendance.Columns[i].HeaderText;
        }
        e.Row.Cells[0].ToolTip = "Lock";
        e.Row.Cells[1].ToolTip = "Leave";
        e.Row.Cells[2].ToolTip = "Error";
    }
    try
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label lblActDate = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblActDate");
            string actDate = lblActDate.Text;

            GridView gv = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gvChildGrid");

            ////GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)gv.Parent.Parent;
            ////int idx = row.RowIndex;
            //////grid.Rows[myRow.RowIndex]
            ////Label ldate = (Label)gv.Rows[idx].FindControl("lblSwipeDate");
            gv.DataSource = sHandler.getChildAttendance(Convert.ToString(empCode), actDate);
            gv.DataBind();

            Label lblShiftStatus = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblShiftStatus");
            string day = lblShiftStatus.Text.Trim();
            if (day == "HOLIDAY")
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Bisque;

            }
            Image iError = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("iError");
            iError.Visible = false;

            Label lblFirstIn = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblFirstIn");
            string firstIn = lblFirstIn.Text.Trim();
            if (firstIn == "")
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
                iError.Visible = true;

            }

            Label lblLastOut = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblLastOut");
            string lastOut = lblLastOut.Text.Trim();
            if (lastOut == "")
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
                iError.Visible = true;

            }

            if (firstIn == "" && lastOut == "")
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Bisque;
                iError.Visible = true;
            }

            DateTime dtActDate = Convert.ToDateTime(actDate);
            DateTime firstDayOfTheMonth = new DateTime(dtActDate.Year, dtActDate.Month, 1);

            DataTable dtLockProcess = sHandler.getLockProcess(Convert.ToString(firstDayOfTheMonth));
            Image iLock = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("iLock");
            ImageButton IBAction = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("IBAction");
            Image imgdiv = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("img");

            if (dtLockProcess.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (dtLockProcess.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "Y")
                {
                    iLock.Visible = true;
                    IBAction.Visible = false;
                    //imgdiv.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    iLock.Visible = false;
                    IBAction.Visible = true;
                    //imgdiv.Visible = true;
                }

            }


            Label lblPermission = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblPermission");
            if (lblPermission.Text == "0")
            {
                lblPermission.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                lblPermission.Enabled = true;
            }

            Image iLeave = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("iLeave");
            iLeave.Visible = false;
            DataTable dtLeave = sHandler.getLeave(Convert.ToString(empCode), actDate);
            if (dtLeave.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (dtLeave.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "M" || dtLeave.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "A")
                {
                    iLeave.ImageUrl = "images/Icon_forenoon.Jpg";
                    iLeave.Visible = true;
                }
                if (dtLeave.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "N")
                {
                    iLeave.ImageUrl = "images/Icon_fullday.Jpg";
                    iLeave.Visible = true;
                    e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;

                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: `JavaScript:divexpandcollapsenew` i dont see that anywhere

Comment: Have you tried to put a few "alerts" in the toggle code.  Then you know if it is actually being fired?